# scrapy deltafetch configuration not working

Tags: python, scrapy

With deltafetch enabled, scrapy is still crawling previously crawled urls.

System is RHEL 6.5

```
[root@hostname ~]# python -V
Python 2.6.6
```

I've installed deltafetch via pip:

```
[root@hostname ~]# pip search scrapy
Scrapy                    - A high-level Python Screen Scraping framework
  INSTALLED: 0.18.4
  LATEST:    0.22.2

[root@hostname ~]# pip search scrapylib
scrapylib                 - Scrapy helper functions and processors
  INSTALLED: 1.1.3 (latest)

/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/scrapylib/deltafetch.py
```

I've configured my settings.py thus:

```
SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapylib.deltafetch.DeltaFetch': 100,
}

DELTAFETCH_ENABLED = True
DOTSCRAPY_ENABLED = True
```

When I run the spider, DeltaFetch appears to be enabled:

```
2014-06-20 10:58:00-0400 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware,
DeltaFetch, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
```

The .scrapy directory is created:

```
[user@hostname output]$ ls -al ../.scrapy
total 12
drwxrwxr-x. 3 user user 4096 Jun 20 10:58 .
drwxrwxr-x. 6 user user 4096 Jun 20 10:58 ..
drwxrwxr-x. 2 user user 4096 Jun 20 10:58 deltafetch
```

The db file is being created:

```
[user@hostname output]$ ls -al ../.scrapy/deltafetch/
total 16
drwxrwxr-x. 2 user user  4096 Jun 20 10:58 .
drwxrwxr-x. 3 user user  4096 Jun 20 10:58 ..
-rw-rw-r--. 1 user user 12288 Jun 20 10:58 spider.db

[user@hostname deltafetch]$ file spider.db 
spider.db: Berkeley DB (Hash, version 9, native byte-order)
[user@hostname deltafetch]$
```

However the .db file appears to have no state data:

```
[user@hostname deltafetch]$ python
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Nov 21 2013, 10:50:32) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import bsddb
>>> for k, v in bsddb.hashopen("spider.db").iteritems(): print k, v
... 
>>> 

[user@hostname deltafetch]$ db_dump spider.db 
VERSION=3
format=bytevalue
type=hash
db_pagesize=4096
HEADER=END
DATA=END
```

When I run the spider again, all the same urls are crawled/fetched and even though there were new items in the crawl, the state db did not get appear to get updated, eg .this is previously fetched file:

```
2014-06-20 11:13:56-0400 [spider] DEBUG: Crawled (200)
<GET http://www.example.com/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx.xml>
(referer: None)
```

I can see not only from the log that the files are still being crawled, but the .xml files that I create from the crawl are getting created again.

I've looked at the other related deltafetch questions and they did not address this issue, any assistance appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved.

This is due to what I believe may be a bug in scrapy, or maybe just a feature.

My spider was simply crawling a web directory, taking the response body and writing it to a file:

```
    def parse_funstuff(self, response):
        filename = response.url.split("/")[-1]
        open(filename, 'wb').write(response.body)
```

As far as scrapy/deltafetch was concerned, this was not scraping anything. I noticed I was seeing the "GET" requests in the log, but not "Scraped from".

I resolved this by adding an item to the spider to contain an arbitrary field I extract from the xml file I'm downloading. Scrapy now populates that item, writes it to the output.xml file, all my target xml's are downloaded, and deltafetch works as expected.

I suspect that if I had written the xml file downloads as items and then wrote them out to files, I would not have had this issue. As soon as I can figure out how to do that (neither python nor scrapy are my areas of expertise) and test it then I can remove the item that I'm currently just populating with an arbitrary extract.